# Catch transaction rejection- moralis

Tags: javascript, reactjs, metamask, moralis

Hi I am working with Moralis using the 1inch plugin. I am having a hard time understanding where to catch a transaction rejection error. IE when I reject the transaction I would like to give a message of sorts. Thanks.

```
async function trySwap() {
      let address = Moralis.User.current().get("ethAddress");
      let amount = Number(fromAmount) * 10**fromTokenDecimals;
      if (tokenSymbol !== "ETH") {
        const allowance = await Moralis.Plugins.oneInch.hasAllowance({
          chain: "eth", // The blockchain you want to use (eth/bsc/polygon)
          fromTokenAddress: tokenAddress, // The token you want to swap
          fromAddress: address, // Your wallet address
          amount: amount,
        });
        if (!allowance) {
          await Moralis.Plugins.oneInch.approve({
            chain: "eth", // The blockchain you want to use (eth/bsc/polygon)
            tokenAddress: tokenAddress, // The token you want to swap
            fromAddress: address, // Your wallet address
          });
        }
      }
      try {
        await doSwap(address, amount);
        alert("Swap Complete");
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        alert('Insufficient ETH')
      }
    }
    
    function doSwap(userAddress, amount) {
      return Moralis.Plugins.oneInch.swap({
        chain: "eth", // The blockchain you want to use (eth/bsc/polygon)
        fromTokenAddress: tokenAddress, // The token you want to swap
        toTokenAddress: totokenAddress, // The token you want to receive
        amount: amount,
        fromAddress: userAddress, // Your wallet address
        slippage: 1,
      })
    }
```

and this is the error

```
MetaMask - RPC Error: MetaMask Tx Signature: User denied transaction signature. 
Object { code: 4001, message: "MetaMask Tx Signature: User denied transaction signature." }
inpage.js:1:51499
Uncaught (in promise) 
Object { code: 4001, message: "MetaMask Tx Signature: User denied transaction signature.", stack:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to edit your code a bit : add `catch` with `then`. Here is a example:

```
async function trySwap(params) {
        const { fromToken, fromAmount, chain } = params;
        const amount = Moralis.Units.Token(fromAmount, fromToken.decimals).toString();
        if (fromToken.address !== "0xeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee") {
          await Moralis.Plugins.oneInch
            .hasAllowance({
              chain, // The blockchain you want to use (eth/bsc/polygon)
              fromTokenAddress: fromToken.address, // The token you want to swap
              fromAddress: walletAddress, // Your wallet address
              amount,
            })
            .then(async (allowance) => {
              console.log(allowance);
              if (!allowance) {
                await Moralis.Plugins.oneInch.approve({
                  chain, // The blockchain you want to use (eth/bsc/polygon)
                  tokenAddress: fromToken.address, // The token you want to swap
                  fromAddress: walletAddress, // Your wallet address
                });
              }
            })
            .catch((e) => alert(e.message));
        }
```

Comment: Thanks that is exactly what I needed!

Comment: thanks. was looking for this